A question in writing is_container and output STL data
My code is
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_container : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_container <T, std::void_t<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>())), decltype(std::end(std::declval<T>()))>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct is_container<T[N]> :std::true_type {};

// fun1
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<is_container<T>::value>::type printElement(const T& v) {
    for (const auto& i : v) {
        printElement(i);
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

// fun2
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!is_container<T>::value>::type printElement(const T& v) {
    std::cout << v << '  '<<'\t';
}



When I use it to output a nested vector, it can't compile and error message is:
C2672 "printElement":No matching overloaded function found
Interestingly, if I swap the position of fun1 and fun2, it works! But why?

Please [edit] and post a [mre] (including the exact call that produced the error message).

Order matter when you're doing this kind of overloading.

fun2 needs to be above fun1, because printElement in the loop of fun1 is actually calling fun2 (for elements which are not containers).

simpler example same problem: https://godbolt.org/z/vGrxK7Pjx

Templates can only call functions declared below themselves if those functions are found via ADL. Either add a declaration of the second function above the first one, or instead of the functions create a class template (with a non-template function in it) that you specialize. (Specializations are not this sensitive to declaration order.)

Hint: if you replace std::declval<T>() with std::declval<T&>(), it is not necessary to specialize the type trait for array types.

Aside: you are approximating the concept std::ranges::range
